# kubernetes can't pull image from private docker registry

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-machine, kubectl, minikube

to reproduce this case, i follow those tutorials first:

**DOCKER - part**

1. [part 1](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-docker-compose-on-ubuntu-18-04)
2. [part 2](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04)
3. [part 3](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate-for-nginx-in-ubuntu-18-04)
4. [part 4](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-private-docker-registry-on-ubuntu-18-04)

***( ... All those parts was done on a ubuntu 18 virtual machine ... )***

After those tutorials, this is the result:

[image: first-part.png]

Here you can see all the step in order to make it works on my local machine (mac os - Mojave)

**KUBERNETES - part**

I follow this tutorial:

1. [part 1](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/)

And you will see the error on the next image:

[image: second-part.png]

All those steps are don on my local machine (mac os - Mojave)

I don't know what is the problem.
I don't know how to solve this

Can somebody help me with this, please?

I really want to understand this

Really thanks

Comment: did you try: `mydockerserver.com:5000/test-juio-image:latest` ? add tag `:latest` into image path

Comment: hello @ThanhNguyenVan i try too and this is the error (the same) `Failed to pull image "mydockerserver.com:5000/test-julio-image:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: Get https://mydockerserver.com:5000/v2/: http: server gave HTTP response to HTTPS client`. I don't understand where is the problem ....

Comment: you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982044/kubernetes-does-not-pull-docker-image-from-private-repository-without-https

Comment: Did you see on my post, the first image , **step-1** ? i have my insecure-registry defined. and also on the same image .. if you see, with docker i can pull the image without problem. The problem is kubernetes doesn't understand the place from where i have to take the image.

Comment: how is `cat /etc/docker/daemon.json` ?

Comment: this is my actual daemon.json [image](https://imgur.com/A20Tznj)
the same that you can see on step-1 from my post  ... the first image

Answer (score 0):

You want to pull it from local repo which is not https, add configuration to allow pull from insecure repository. find docker.conf file which for me is in this path `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf` and add below line

```
[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --insecure-egistry=<repo-address>:<port>
```

Comment: and can you explain me how i do that ? - or what steps i have to follow to tell kybernetes configuration ... "you have to pull the images from my private docker registry ... "
i don't know if it helps but i can see the catalag in this form - [image](https://imgur.com/XWLr0nN)

Comment: do what i said in my answer but don't forget to restart docker daemon after that.

Comment: but `/etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/docker.conf` is not for mac ... rigth?
because i didn't find it ...

Comment: check following link  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38785991/docker-deamon-config-path-under-mac-os

Comment: on windows/mac there is a config editor to the tray icon UI

Comment: from the UI docker, there is a link that explain about the config part (see [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file) ) but reading, no there is MAC option, just LINUX and WINDOWS

Comment: check this one https://softwaretester.info/docker-for-mac-with-insecure-private-registry/

Comment: reading the site, explain, how to push and pull images to a privacy registry. But if you see well on my first image [HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1010.png) i can make a pull from my docker privacy registry (this is allocated on a virtual machine - Ubuntu 18) , obviously i made a push before .... this is my actual catalog [IMAGE](https://imgur.com/reb6Imz)

Comment: found this on github check if it can solve your problem. https://github.com/docker/distribution/issues/1874 and this one too https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28321

Comment: Hello thanks, but again this is for docker... i resolve that problem too. My problem now is with kubernetes. Kubernetes need make an image pull.... and when i read the pod describe I see the error that now you know.

Comment: The --insecure-skip-tls-verify=true flag allows ignoring insecure certificates in kubectl

Comment: Helo again, i hope i'm doing rigth, but if you see here [IMAGE - 1](https://imgur.com/VEE28QL), i'm using the flag ... and on this image [IMAGE - 2](https://imgur.com/kOd1s8c) i see the same error. Why is so complicated this ?

Comment: kubernetes uses docker service to perform actions like pull or push. I think your kubernetes configurations is fine but your docker service configuration need to change. someone suggested add the line I said in my answer to daemon.json in this path  ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/database/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/etc/docker. create it if does not exist already

Comment: Hello again, but can you tell me what Mac Os version you are using?, i have Mojave and "Containers" Folder doesn't exist [**image**](https://imgur.com/RmDQYXI)

Comment: I don't have macOS, just googled and all of them pointed to this path. another example is here :https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/1156.

Answer (score 0):

I think that issue is caused because your did not add your dockerserver as secure registry.

You should add your registry to `daemon.json` file.
You have to create or modify `/etc/docker/daemon.json` on the machine.

`$ sudo vi /etc/docker/daemon.json` (you can use nano or other text editor)
Inside the file you have to add your repository. It should looks like

```
{
  "insecure-registries" : ["mydockerserver.com:5000"]
}
```

After this change you must restart docker daemon using

```
$ sudo service docker restart
```

Also in your yaml you should use:

```
...
  image: mydockerserver.com:5000/test-julie-image:latest
...
```

Please let me know if that helped.

Comment: I tried this but still the k8s pod fails to start. Docker pull works though. The error with k8s pod is "Error from server (BadRequest): container "my-app" in pod "my-deployment-695b96dc66-4mzdn" is waiting to start: image can't be pulled". Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit old but I ran into this post searching for the same solutions.  The link below is what worked for me:

https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/local-registry/

When reading the script pay close attention to the code below:

```
# create a cluster with the local registry enabled in containerd
cat <<EOF | kind create cluster --config=-
kind: Cluster
apiVersion: kind.x-k8s.io/v1alpha4
containerdConfigPatches:
- |-
  [plugins."io.containerd.grpc.v1.cri".registry.mirrors."localhost:${reg_port}"]
    endpoint = ["http://${reg_name}:${reg_port}"]
EOF
```

AND

```
# Document the local registry
# https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/tree/master/keps/sig-cluster-lifecycle/generic/1755-communicating-a-local-registry
cat <<EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: local-registry-hosting
  namespace: kube-public
data:
  localRegistryHosting.v1: |
    host: "localhost:${reg_port}"
    help: "https://kind.sigs.k8s.io/docs/user/local-registry/"
EOF
```

Even if you aren't using "kind," and you have installed a local custom solutions this code above should provide some insights or guidance.